# IOPS limits on EC2 with EBS mounting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, amazon-ebs

I had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634584/aws-iops-limit-during-load-test) on IOPS limit where in EC2 instance does not use EBS. This question deals with EC2 instance with Elastic Block storage. The environment goes as -

- Two c4.8xlarge EC2 instances, one [c4.8xlarge](http://%09%207800%20req/sec%20throughput%20is%20for%20read%20operation,%20modifying%20my%20question%20to%20reflect%20it%20better.%20If%20you%20wanted%20to%20post%20it%20as%20answer%20then%20please%20post%20it%20in%20answer%20block%20:-)) instance supports 500 MB/s throughput
- Connection pool is 2049
- Got rid of [DNS Cache](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)
- EBS storage of 120 GB with each instance
- Application is load tested with JMeter 2.13 for one hour on distributed mode using 10 m4.4xlarge instance
- Test is executed with 700 threads with ramp up period of 30 mins and then continues with all 700 threads for 30 mins.
- There are two APIs being load tested one has Write Operation (Post Request) and other had Read Operation (Get Request)
- Test reaches throughput of 7800 requests/sec for read operation and 300 requests/sec for write operation with 400 threads and stays at ~7800 requests/sec irrespective of the threads increasing up to 700 threads.
- Following are the graphs of Read and Write Throughput during tests for EBS -

[image]
[image]

- And this is how average Read and Write size appear to be during test - 
  [image]

Considering graphs above could I safely assume that I am not hit by IOPS limit?

Comment: 7800 requests per second. Each request is 60 kB so total is 468000 KB which is around 460 MB/sec. for c4.8xlarge it is 500 MB per second is the max as per this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7800 requests per second. Each request is 4 KB for read. So, total is 31200 KB, which is around 31 MB/sec. For write it comes around 18 MB/sec as per your data. For c4.8xlarge 500 MB per second is the max as per this: [EBS EC2 Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html).

The throughput depends on the EBS volume size. The current ratio is 30:1 as per: [EBS IOPS:GB ratio](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/09/ebs-provisioned-iops-maximum-iops-gb-ratio-increased-to-30-1/).

So, for 120 GB on c4.8xlarge, you need to get 3600 Mbps or 450 MB/sec.

Also, did you try increasing the number of m4.4xlarge instances or using a much powerful m4.10x instances. May be that can also be a bottleneck.
What was the CPU usage on these instances when the tests were running?

Comment: so considering both read and write operation, total IOPS is ~ 50MB/sec (i.e. 31MB/s and 18MB/s), and given that c4.8xlarge has max bandwidth of 500MB I am way belore IOPS limit, is not it?

Comment: Also, from what I know max throughput is 30 times your EBS volume in GB. So, for 120, you get 3600 Mbps or 450 MB/sec as throughput. 4000 Mbps or 500 MB/sec is max for c4.8xlarge as per the document above. So, for 120 GB EBS the limit is 450. Also, edited the answer to include this.

Comment: Also, did you try increasing the number of m4.4xlarge instances or using a much powerful m4.10x instances. May be that can also be a bottleneck. What was the CPU usage on these instances when the tests were running?

Comment: test agents show minimal cpu or load average during test execution. I reached the same amount of throughput when running test from 6 test agents with 110 threads on each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100153/discussion-between-tarun-and-sri-u).